# How to make date as a column in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, time-series, algorithmic-trading

```
                    1. open 2. high 3. low  4. close
date                
2020-07-24 18:12:00 1508.21 1508.21 1508.21  1508.21
2020-07-24 18:07:00 1504.75 1504.75 1504.75  1504.75
2020-07-24 17:00:00 1507.00 1507.00 1507.00 1507.00
2020-07-24 16:58:00 1507.76 1507.76 1507.76 1507.76
2020-07-24 16:49:00 1509.32 1509.32 1509.32 1509.32
```

Here when I am writing `data.columns` date is not being displayed as a column.
I want to make the date column as a column of the dataframe.
How can I do so? Please help me!

Comment: reset the index `data = data.reset_index()`

Comment: Thank you so much! Please upvote my question!